# Magento Admin Issue: "admin/url/custom" missing from "core_config_data"

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, database, admin-panel, 404

I stupidly applied a custom admin url within the Admin Panel. I know I know, I am suppose to do it in the local.xml but it kicked up an error.

I have attempted to remove the instance from database but I can't find the "admin/url/custom" row in "core_config_data". I've cleared my browser cache, I've deleted the "var/cache" and "var/session" folder and still no luck.

I've tried similar solutions to questions regarding getting a 404, but since the row doesn't exist I am unable to change it.

It boggles where the website is getting the custom url from. I tried searching the database but unable to find it anywhere.

When I remove the "custom" part of the admin url I can get logged in, but all the styling has disappeared. I tried removing the url from the Admin Panel in it's current state but it won't save my option.

Any advice appreciated.

I am using Magento 1.9.2.4.

Many thanks, 
Lisa

Answer (score 2):

Can you check if your core_config_data entries for path: admin/url/use_custom and admin/url/use_custom_path are both set to a 0 value. If you don't want to use the custom URL added from the admin panel, setting both the above to 0 should reset this for you.